# Flatten/refactor data set for alert array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a d3.js gannt chart - and I've got the following data set coming out - but I need to flatten the array by date, then also group it by type -- so there is one entry for the starting/ending time and refactor a tool tip textual parameter that can showcase the grouped information

So like on hovering on a bar -- it reads (Device: pH, Humidity)(Report: Swelling)(Clinician Assessment: Pain Level)

What would be the best approach to refactoring this data set to something as mentioned.

```
let array = [
{text: "pH", starting_time: 1693347129000, ending_time: 1693350729000, type: "device"},
{text: "humidity", starting_time: 1693347129000, ending_time: 1693350729000, type: "device"},
{text: "pH", starting_time: 1693339929000, ending_time: 1693343529000, type: "device"},
{text: "pH", starting_time: 1692958329000, ending_time: 1692961929000, type: "device"},
{text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692958329000, ending_time: 1692961929000, type: "device"},
{text: "pH", starting_time: 1692738729000, ending_time: 1692742329000, type: "device"},
{text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692738729000, ending_time: 1692742329000, type: "device"},
{text: "temperature", starting_time: 1692735129000, ending_time: 1692738729000, type: "device"},
{text: "pH", starting_time: 1692735129000, ending_time: 1692738729000, type: "device"},
{text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692213729000, ending_time: 1692217329000, type: "device"},
{text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692130929000, ending_time: 1692134529000, type: "device"},
{text: "pain level", starting_time: 1695972618000, ending_time: 1695976218000, type: "report"},
{text: "swelling", starting_time: 1695597028000, ending_time: 1695600628000, type: "report"},
{text: "level of pain", starting_time: 1695597028000, ending_time: 1695600628000, type: "clinicianAssessment"}
]
```

would it be something like this

```
function alertBreakdown(result){
    let schedule = [...result];

    //flat all the dates to one array
    const timestamps = schedule.flatMap(_ => _.starting_time);

    //flatten also for ending_time? so if same starting/ending time?

    //console.log("timestamps", timestamps);

    //count the occurrences of each date in a dictionary structure
    const day2count = {};
    timestamps.forEach(timestamp => {
        //console.log("--<timestamp", timestamp);
        const day = moment(timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD");//.toString().split('T')[0];
        //const day = timestamp.toString().split('T')[0];
        day2count[day] = (day2count[day] || 0) + 1;
    });

    //console.log("day2count", day2count);
       
    // convert the map to an array of entries
    const scheduleResult = Object.entries(day2count).map(([date, value]) => ({date: moment(date), value: value, toolTipText: "test" }))
          .sort((a,b) => moment(a.date) - moment(b.date))

    return scheduleResult;

}
```

output array something like this - where the starting_time/ending_time is unique - and the types are grouped

```
let array = [
{text: "Device: pH, humidity", starting_time: 1693347129000, ending_time: 1693350729000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: pH", starting_time: 1693339929000, ending_time: 1693343529000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: pH, humidity", starting_time: 1692958329000, ending_time: 1692961929000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: pH, humidity", starting_time: 1692738729000, ending_time: 1692742329000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: temperature, pH", starting_time: 1692735129000, ending_time: 1692738729000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: humidity", starting_time: 1692213729000, ending_time: 1692217329000, type: "device"},
{text: "Device: humidity", starting_time: 1692130929000, ending_time: 1692134529000, type: "device"},
{text: "Report: pain level", starting_time: 1695972618000, ending_time: 1695976218000, type: "report"},
{text: "Report: swelling, Clinician Assessment: level of pain", starting_time: 1695597028000, ending_time: 1695600628000, type: "report, clinicianAssement"},
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the output array that you’re expecting?

Comment: I've updated it to show an output array example. Essentially flatten starting_time/ending_time - so anything left is unique moments in those time ranges to stop creating any bars that overlap each other. Then to compact the groups/text to showcase the type/text to try and start providing a more human reading of the textual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to do the grouping. Below, I'm grouping by a key that's made up of both the starting_time and end_time. For each object, we grab the value from the Map constructed by using the start/end time properties. If the Map's value for the key that we're looking for isn't set yet, we create a new object that will act as the key's value. This object stores the accumulated group data which we update as we see more of the same objects with the same start & end times. Within this grouped object we're storing an inner `Map` called `typeTextMap` which stores the the mappings between the different `type` and `text` for objects with the same start & end time. Once we've looped through the array, we convert the `Map` we've built to the final result by using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to grab the grouped objects for each start & end time group we found, and then also build out the new `text` and `type` values based on the inner `Map` (`typeTextMap`) we built. One of the advantages of using a `Map` here is that when we get the values at this point, we get them in the order they were inserted into the `Map`, which will make the objects appear in the same order as your original array:

```js
function alertBreakdown (arr) {
  const groupedData = new Map();
  
  for (const obj of arr) {
    const key = `${obj.starting_time}$${obj.ending_time}`; // group by "starting_time" and "ending_time" by creating a unique key that combines these: starting_time$ending_time
    let grouped = groupedData.get(key);
    if (!grouped) // if we haven't seen this start/end time combo before, create an object to store the accumulated grouped data
      grouped = {obj}; // store object for later when reconstructing the array
    const typeTextMap = grouped.typeTextMap || new Map(); 
    grouped.typeTextMap = typeTextMap.set(obj.type, [...(typeTextMap.get(obj.type) || []), obj.text]);
    groupedData.set(key, grouped);
  }
  // Using the grouped map's values, reconstruct the array of objects, updating the text and type keys using the grouped data:
  return Array.from(groupedData.values(), ({obj, typeTextMap}) => ({
    ...obj,
    text: Array.from(typeTextMap, ([type, texts]) => `${transformTypeName(type)}: ${texts.join(", ")}`).join(", "),
    type: Array.from(typeTextMap.keys()).join(", ")
  }));
}

const transformTypeName = type => type.replace(/\b[a-z]|[a-z][A-Z]/g, ([fc, sc]) => sc ? fc + " " + sc.toUpperCase() : fc.toUpperCase());

const arr = [ {text: "pH", starting_time: 1693347129000, ending_time: 1693350729000, type: "device"}, {text: "humidity", starting_time: 1693347129000, ending_time: 1693350729000, type: "device"}, {text: "pH", starting_time: 1693339929000, ending_time: 1693343529000, type: "device"}, {text: "pH", starting_time: 1692958329000, ending_time: 1692961929000, type: "device"}, {text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692958329000, ending_time: 1692961929000, type: "device"}, {text: "pH", starting_time: 1692738729000, ending_time: 1692742329000, type: "device"}, {text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692738729000, ending_time: 1692742329000, type: "device"}, {text: "temperature", starting_time: 1692735129000, ending_time: 1692738729000, type: "device"}, {text: "pH", starting_time: 1692735129000, ending_time: 1692738729000, type: "device"}, {text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692213729000, ending_time: 1692217329000, type: "device"}, {text: "humidity", starting_time: 1692130929000, ending_time: 1692134529000, type: "device"}, {text: "pain level", starting_time: 1695972618000, ending_time: 1695976218000, type: "report"}, {text: "swelling", starting_time: 1695597028000, ending_time: 1695600628000, type: "report"}, {text: "level of pain", starting_time: 1695597028000, ending_time: 1695600628000, type: "clinicianAssessment"} ];

console.log(alertBreakdown(arr));
```

Note that I've also created a function called `transformTypeName` which converts `camelCase` type names into spaced text such as `Camel Case`. This is to try and match your expected output, however, I'd suggest that you store the expected labels on your original array of objects so you don't have to do this transformation via code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `TrueSet` instead of a `Map` isn't just simpler; it's more powerful.

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [
        {text: "pH", start: 1693347129000, end: 1693350729000, type: "device"},
        {text: "humidity", start: 1693347129000, end: 1693350729000, type: "device"},
        {text: "pH", start: 1693339929000, end: 1693343529000, type: "device"},
        {text: "pH", start: 1692958329000, end: 1692961929000, type: "device"},
        {text: "humidity", start: 1692958329000, end: 1692961929000, type: "device"},
        {text: "pH", start: 1692738729000, end: 1692742329000, type: "device"},
        {text: "humidity", start: 1692738729000, end: 1692742329000, type: "device"},
        {text: "temperature", start: 1692735129000, end: 1692738729000, type: "device"},
        {text: "pH", start: 1692735129000, end: 1692738729000, type: "device"},
        {text: "humidity", start: 1692213729000, end: 1692217329000, type: "device"},
        {text: "humidity", start: 1692130929000, end: 1692134529000, type: "device"},
        {text: "pain level", start: 1695972618000, end: 1695976218000, type: "report"},
        {text: "swelling", start: 1695597028000, end: 1695600628000, type: "report"},
        {text: "level of pain", start: 1695597028000, end: 1695600628000, type: "clinicianAssessment"}
    ].map(item => ({text: item.text, start: new Date(item.start), end: new Date(item.end), type: item.type})),

    expected = [      
      {text: 'humidity', start: '15/8/2023, 22:22:09', end: '15/8/2023, 23:22:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'humidity', start: '16/8/2023, 21:22:09', end: '16/8/2023, 22:22:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'pH, temperature', start: '22/8/2023, 22:12:09', end: '22/8/2023, 23:12:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'humidity, pH', start: '22/8/2023, 23:12:09', end: '23/8/2023, 00:12:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'humidity, pH', start: '25/8/2023, 12:12:09', end: '25/8/2023, 13:12:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'pH', start: '29/8/2023, 22:12:09', end: '29/8/2023, 23:12:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'humidity, pH', start: '30/8/2023, 00:12:09', end: '30/8/2023, 01:12:09', type: 'device'},
      {text: 'level of pain', start: '25/9/2023, 01:10:28', end: '25/9/2023, 02:10:28', type: 'clinicianAssessment'},
      {text: 'swelling', start: '25/9/2023, 01:10:28', end: '25/9/2023, 02:10:28', type: 'report'},
      {text: 'pain level', start: '29/9/2023, 09:30:18', end: '29/9/2023, 10:30:18', type: 'report'}
    ]
```

The `TrueSet` enables the representation of each item through a designated `repr` function. In this case, the representation could contain the `year`, `month`, `day` of both the `start` and `end` of each item, alongside `start`, `end`, `text` and `type`. Adding your data to the `TrueSet` is all that's required.

```
const
    repr = item => [item.start.getFullYear(), 1 + item.start.getMonth(), item.start.getDate(), item.start, item.end.getFullYear(), 1 + item.end.getMonth(), item.end.getDate(), item.end, item.type, item.text],
        
    set = new TrueSet(repr)
       .letAll(data),
```

Voilà! Your data are sorted according to their representation `repr` and classified within an internal tree structure, accessible by `set.classifier`. This structure provides a `views(depth)` method that iterates through all the subtrees at the specified `depth`. In our scenario, at `depth=9` there are the subtrees addressed by:

`[start.year, start.month, start.day, start.date, end.year, end.month, end.day, end.date, item.type]`

Each `view` is a sorted collection of arrays which are expressed relative to the subtree. The initial component of the array is, therefore, the item's `text` property. Joining the texts of all the items in the same view becomes immediate:

`view.then(rel => rel[0]).toArray().join(', ')`.

The `keys()` method of the `view`, in turn, provides the `keys` addressing the subtree represented by the `view`. Thus, we can transform the `view` into a single absolute array, a record.

```
const 
    records = set.classifier.views(9)
        .then(view => [...view.keys(), view.then(rel => rel[0]).toArray().join(', ')])
```

Converting each record into an object can be easily accomplished by:

```
const 
    got = records.
        .then(record => ({text: record[9], start: record[3].toLocaleString(), end: record[7].toLocaleString(), type: record[8]}))
```

If you're acquainted with the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library, you'll recognize that each iteration provided by the library offers various methods to restrict, compose, and transform the iteration. The `then(f)` method applies a function `f` to each item, similar to the `map(f)` method of the Array class.

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(got.toArray(), expected)
```

It's essential to highlight that the `TrueSet` and its inner `Classifier` offer numerous ways to report your data. For example, retrieving all items starting on a given `day` or perhaps all items of a specific `type` starting on a given `day` can be effortlessly achieved...